# Zend Sqlite utf 8

Tags: php, zend-framework, sqlite

sorry to bother you.

I'm wondering if using utf 8 in sqlite 
is the same of mysql therefore it's enough 
set this lines in application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_SQLITE" 

resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook.db" 

resources.db.params.charset = UTF8 

resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true 


or I should do a query in my bootstrap like

PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
```

BTW where does zf do the work (I mean in which class) ?

Bye.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see anything in

- http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Sqlite.php

that suggests a charset option will be applied if given.

Comment: You agree while in the Pdo/Mysql there is $this->_config['charset'] there isn't any in Pdo/Sqlite. Thanks just a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

In The Definitive Guide 
to SQLite I found 
[Some settings such as page size and character encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, 
etc.) cannot be changed once the database is created, so this interim is where you have a chance 
to specify them.]

So you should set the utf 8 encoding in the script where you create the DB.